# Spring Tool Suite folder names are too long

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I have started using Spring Tool Suite but the folder names are tool long e.g `com.webhook.springrestful.authorization.data`

[image]

Is there a means to make it show only relative Paths in project folders like this screenshot from Intellij IDEA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Window > **Preferences: Java > Appearance*** there are the two following options for that which are disabled by default:

- ***Compress all package name segments, except the final segment*** to hide the first part and
- ***Abbreviate package names*** to specify shorter replacements for known package name prefixes

Comment: With more help i got from Martin Lippert from twitter https://twitter.com/martinlippert/status/1265629231444303872 am going to mark this as best answer.